# Pause and restart a thread in infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm in need of a requirement which is like as follows.

- I have a jsp contains enable and disable radio buttons.
- if i click on enable, a process should execute with an interval of time like      for each and every 2 or 3 hours.
- if disable is clicked and submitted, the
  current executing task should pause until and unless again the enable
  is submitted/clicked from the jsp(if enabled the above step should
  continue to execute).

  ```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
  {


      //first time execution
      if(request.getParameter("lic").equals("enable") && counter==0)
      {
          t1.start();
          counter++;
          System.out.println(counter);
      }


      //if already started and clicks re-enable
      else if(request.getParameter("lic").equals("enable") && counter>0)
      {
          System.out.println("thread already started");
          t1.interrupt();
      }

      //for long pausing of thread
      else if(request.getParameter("lic").equals("disable"))
      {
          System.out.println("thread is going to pause");
          try 
          {
              Thread.sleep(20000);
              System.out.println("slept for 20 seconds");
          } 
          catch (InterruptedException e) 
          {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              System.out.println("interrupted while sleeping");
          }

      }
  }
  static int counter = 0;
  static Thread t1 = new Thread()
  {
      public void run()
      {
          System.out.println("hi thread is executed");
      }   
  };
  ```

  }

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i need to monitor a server. when its process > 80 i have to send a mail to admin automatically. 
my code should check the server continuously for each and every hour.
i need to enable/disable this option through jsp.
everything is working except the time.